# How to configure an ASP .NET OWIN identity on multiple projects

Tags: asp.net-identity

Did someone can explain me how to authenticate users on multiple projects ?
To explain the context, I have 2 MVC 5 web applications, the 2 are using the OWIN authentication and everythig works well, but I don't find the way to bind the two authentications between them, when I log on to a project, I'm kicked out of the other.

I configured a machinekey (I tried from VS on IIS Local and Express) on both web.config as mentionned elsewhere, but not seems to be the way..?

If someone can explain me how to do..? Maybe by configuring the app.UseCookieAuthentication ??

Thank in advance.

Comment: are you talking about localhost?